# jQuery - Return true only if anchor href contains URL only

Tags: jquery, html

I have one jQuery function which executes for each anchor tag from the page which needs to be checked that acnhor tag should contains herf attribute with URL of any site. It should return false in case if anchor tag does not contains href tag or href tag having the values link blank, mailto, #, tel:1000 etc.

Means condition should check anchor tag should have href tag & hreg tag should contain URL only.

```
$('a').each(function() {   //add a class to all external links
    var $a  = jQuery(this);
    var domainURL = $a.get(0).href;
    var hostToDetectAsExternal = domainURL.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').replace('www.','').split(/[/?#]/)[0];

    if(domainURL != '' && domainURL.indexOf('javascript') == -1 && allwedHostsArray.indexOf(hostToDetectAsExternal) == -1) // -1 : Not found in a allowed hosts array & not found javacript in a URL
    {
        $a.addClass('external-link');
    }
});
```

have written this code but not fulfilling all the conditions. Please anyone help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Use the selector string `a[href^="http"]` to select `a`s whose `href` attributes start with `http` (which, of course, will also include those which start with `https`)

```
$('a[href^="http"]').each(function() {
```

If you wanted to include *all* URL-based `href`s and not just external links or absolute paths, you could add `a[href^="/"]` as well, to match `a`s with relative URLs:

```
$('a[href^="http"], a[href^="/"]').each(function() {
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)